# C file can't see a variable declared in included file

Tags: c, file, compiler-errors, compilation, header

I have three files. `test.c` `test.h` and `use.c`. Code in each of them looks like:

test.h:

```
#pragma once

#define unused __attribute__((unused))

typedef int cmd_fun_t(struct tokens *tokens);
typedef struct fun_desc {
  cmd_fun_t *fun;
  char *cmd;
  char *doc;
} fun_desc_t;

int cmd_exit(struct tokens *tokens);
int cmd_help(struct tokens *tokens);
int cmd_pwd(struct tokens *tokens);
int cmd_cd(struct tokens *tokens);
```

test.c:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>

#include "test.h"
#include "tokenizer.h"


fun_desc_t cmd_table[] = {
  {cmd_help, "?", "show this help menu"},
  {cmd_exit, "exit", "exit the command shell"},
  {cmd_pwd, "pwd", "print working directory"},
  {cmd_cd, "cd", "change directory"},
};

int cmd_pwd(unused struct tokens *tokens){
  char cwd[8192];
  if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
      fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", cwd);
  else
      perror("Error Occured");

  return 1;
}

int cmd_cd(unused struct tokens *tokens){
  if(chdir(tokens_get_token(tokens, 1)) == -1){
    fprintf(stdout, "No such file or directory.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  return 1;
}

/* Prints a helpful description for the given command */
int cmd_help(unused struct tokens *tokens) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(cmd_table) / sizeof(fun_desc_t); i++)
    printf("%s - %s\n", cmd_table[i].cmd, cmd_table[i].doc);
  return 1;
}

/* Exits this shell */
int cmd_exit(unused struct tokens *tokens) {
  exit(0);
}
```

use.c:

```
#include "test.h"
int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(cmd_table); i++){

    }
    return 0;
}
```

my assumption is this should work well but when I compile the code, it gives the following error:

> ‘cmd_table’ undeclared (first use in this function)    for(int i = 0;
>   i < sizeof(cmd_table); i++)

Any suggestions why this happens?

Comment: What exactly should `sizeof(cmd_table)` be, according to you? I don't understand this. `cmd_table` is nevertheless declared in a .c file, which is not in scope for `use.c`.

Comment: yes but it is global. Shouldn't use.c see globals of test.c

Comment: Were you able to compile test.c?

Comment: What makes you think that `use.c` can "see" `cmd_table`?

Comment: ...anyway accessing `cmd_table` from outside of  `test.c` is poor design.

Comment: In order to do global spaghetti programming, main must have an `extern fun_desc_t cmd_table[]`. However, this is very bad practice - it is much better to write a proper getter function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cmd_table` is defined in `test.c`. If you want it to be visible to the compiler when it is compiling other C files, there needs to be an `extern` declaration visible when it is compiling the other files. The usual way to do this is to put the `extern` declaration in the header.

```
// in test.h
extern fun_desc_t cmd_table[];
```

Unfortunately, that won't tell you how big the array is. For lookup tables, like this, a common way to solve this problem is to put a null sentinel value at the end.

```
fun_desc_t cmd_table[] = {
  {cmd_help, "?", "show this help menu"},
  {cmd_exit, "exit", "exit the command shell"},
  {cmd_pwd, "pwd", "print working directory"},
  {cmd_cd, "cd", "change directory"},
  {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
```

And you change the loop in `main` as follows

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; cmd_table[i].fun != NULL; i++)
    {
        // Do whatever
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct answer, but doing this is bad design.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well, I was contemplating also giving a completely encapsulated solution but it was lunchtime, and I was hungry.

Answer (score 1):

cmd_table is declared in test.c file and you are using it in use.c file. As scope of cmd_table is limited to test.c file you can not use it in use.c file

Comment: I just put it in c file but now when I compile it says that the cmd_table is defined somewhere else, which is definitely not

Comment: I moved it in header, and now compilation says its defined somewhere else, but it's not. I've checked many times and it's not

Comment: You need to declare extern variable in header file to use it in both .c files